# I am trying to make a simple launcher for android. But the app crashes when I move from my start activity to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

03-16 14:53:17.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1834): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.slaunch/com.example.slaunch.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #154: Error inflating class

THE XML FILE

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff000000"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layoutMode="opticalBounds"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rowCount="8" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            style="@style/AppTheme"
            android:layout_width="161dp"
            android:layout_height="161dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/barcode" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="3dp"


            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/text" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/whatsapp" />
              <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/skype" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/locationnotifier" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/screenreading" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/custombrowser" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/call" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"

            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/currencyrecognition" />
 <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton11"

            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/settings" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/colorrecognition" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton12"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/app_drawer" />

    </GridLayout>

  </ScrollView>
```

MAIN ACTIVITY.JAVA

```
package com.example.slaunch;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public ImageButton caller;
    public ImageButton message;
    public ImageButton browser;
    public ImageButton setting;
    public ImageButton apps;
    public ImageButton barcodeScan;
    public ImageButton textspeech;
    public ImageButton skype;
    public ImageButton whatsapp;
    public ImageButton viber ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        if(((myapp)getApplication()).getViewSize()==1)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        }
        else if(((myapp)getApplication()).getViewSize()==2)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.size_two);  
        }
        else if(((myapp)getApplication()).getViewSize()==3)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.size_three);    
        }
        else if(((myapp)getApplication()).getViewSize()==4)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.size_three);    
        }
        else if(((myapp)getApplication()).getViewSize()==5)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.size_threebrown);   
        }
        else if(((myapp)getApplication()).getViewSize()==6)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.largest_size);  
        }



         caller= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
          caller.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
                startActivity(intent); 

            }
        });

          message= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
          message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");


                //intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"));
             startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
          browser= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
          browser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.slaunch.WebBrowser");
            //intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");


                //intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"));
             startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
          setting= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton11);
          setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.slaunch.LauncherSettings");
            //intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");


                //intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"));
             startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
          apps= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton12);
          apps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.slaunch.applist");
            //intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");


                //intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"));
             startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
          barcodeScan= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
          barcodeScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //  Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.slaunch.barcodeScan");
            //intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");


                //intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"));
            // startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
          textspeech= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
          textspeech.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.slaunch.textToSpeech");
            //intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");


                //intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"));
            // startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
          skype= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton10);
          skype.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //  Intent intent = new Intent("com.skype.raider");
            //intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");


                //intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"));
            // startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your xml file which is used in activity

Comment: XML file in the updated question,

Comment: on which API level do you try do this?

Comment: I tested your layout and it works fine. Are you sure that it is right error. Could you clear your logcat and reproduce issue one more time and post new error message or make sure that it is the same as in post

Comment: 03-16 15:31:13.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1805): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 15:31:13.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1805): Process: com.example.slaunch, PID: 1805
03-16 15:31:13.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1805): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.slaunch/com.example.slaunch.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #156: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-16 15:31:13.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)

This is what it says again.

Comment: Do you use above xml in MainActivity class? For give me my question but this situation is very strange for me...

Comment: The problem is in 156 line in xml but there is nothing which can generate this issue  on this line in your xml

Comment: Exactly. That really is frustrating. Thanks for help though.

Comment: Can you post the code from your `MainActivity.java` as well?

Comment: Try create new activity only with this layout - I mean just setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); in onCreate method and try to run it. And check that it works. If not you really have strange issue, if yes post your MainActivity class

Comment: MainActivity.java Added too.

Comment: Ok so how do you know which layout do you use ? and what are you doing in your Activity class?

Comment: comment your big if and try layout by layout. You have to find wrong layout xml